# Does the skull-crusher work the chest isometrically?

Tags: bodybuilding, chest, upper-body-workout, triceps

sometimes I feel my chest slightly working in the skull-crusher. So, I thought it could be normal. In fact, although all the pictures showing the skull-crusher involved muscles shows only the triceps, I think it works also the chest isometrically.

If you look at the following picture, in both the starting and middle positions the arms are horizontally adducted. This means the pecs are constantly squeezed to keep such a position. In practice, the arms are constantly exactly in the same position as the top position of the bench press.

[image]

Do you agree with me? If yes, how much do you feel your chest during the skull-crusher?

Comment: Do you mean a [French press](https://youtu.be/JImgCWzCHwI)? What you have shown I've usually called a skull-crusher.

Comment: @C.Lange Thank you, in my gym it is commonly called French Press, but now I'll replace it with skull-crusher to avoid any ambiguity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chest also pulls the the elbow from overhead position down to your belly, hence why dips, Iron crosses and Pullovers or Front levers and pull ups work your chest.

Muscles have no precise function, they are just elastic ropes of cells that can pull in varied directions based on how you position yourself.

so yes, the chest can get sore from exercises that weren't supposed to get the chest sore.

[image]

As you can see, yes the chest is being used in a skull crusher but not because you are squizing the pecs, but because without the chest pulling the elbows away from your face, then your arms would just crash over your head.

Another drawing to show the relation on how the chest works, same position as the above drawing, just rotated the gravity.

[image]

Comment: if anyone wants to know why the chest is in an advantaged position with the elbows parallel to the shoulders, it's because the chest is not too stretched and not too flexed, the same reason why the bicep is stronger with a supinated forearm than with a proneted one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes every exercise involves muscle isometrics or extremely limited range of motion. Bicep curls uses your back and shoulder for instance, and of course your forearm muscles and hand muscles.

Isometrics are good for recovery and conditioning. With heavy weights or going to an extreme level of strength failure with low weight, of course strength and muscle mass will increase in the muscles working isometrically.

Isometrics above 70% of your max boost recovery, especially in tendons, and it's great for bone development.

Bringing your elbows in requires the pecs though, yes.